# List of entities in package Spring Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm looking for a way to get a List(just String values) of entities in one of project packages. Not all, just specified package.

Is there any way to do this? They're also in mysql database, but they're not sorted there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection for this:

```
Reflections ref = new Reflections("com.your.package");
Set<String> entities = 
ref.getTypesAnnotatedWith(javax.persistence.Entity.class).stream().map(Class::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```